# Get a python program I've written onto Blackberry or other mobile platform?

Tags: python, blackberry, cross-platform

The said program runs only on my PC as of now.

I've been searching through StackOverflow, and I've found out about RhoMobile's Rhodes which allows you to write the app in Ruby once and run it in multiple mobile platforms: iPhone, Symbian, Android, BlackBerry, and Windows Mobile. Is there anything similar for Python? If not how would I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make it web based with an interface that supports mobile browsers :D

Comment: What does making it "web-based" entail?

Comment: I think it means put it on a website. Maybe. I could be wrong.

Comment: Write your own interpreter! That's one way, but perhaps not practical given your goals.

Comment: making it web-based means put your logic into a CGI or other python web framework and design a user interface atop it.  Your presentation layer can detect the user agent (phone, desktop, etc) and use the associated user interface- using a mobile version for people on their phones.  The benefit being users can access the app from they're phones, desktops, nettops etc.  They do of-course, have to be connected to the internet and you have to have your app hosted on the internet. But with their data in 'the cloud' the loss of a device doesn't mean loss of their data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PyJS python-to-javascript cross-"compiler" at http://pyjs.org/ to make your program into a web application, possibly locally stored. This would work on any mobile device with a competent browser with javascript enabled (pretty common nowadays, though it was not the case a few years ago).

It's still extremely buggy though... extremely...

Comment: Speaking specifically for Blackbery, you could then add this to a Webworks project containing extra "glue-code" to call your Python translated to Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but new possibility for Python on BlackBerry, but only on the PlayBook and upcoming BB10 devices.  There's a project called BlackBerry-Py (BB-Py) which you can read about at http://blackberry-py.microcode.ca/ .

It uses a port of PySide and uses the Python 3.2 runtime that's pre-installed on the devices as well as the RIM-product Qt port.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the project leads.

Comment: Seems fascinating! I`ll give it a look. Can it use older implementations of PythonÉ

Comment: Louis93, it uses the 3.2 runtime which is pre-installed, though someone could always just port another version and bundle the libpython.so with the app.  There is a Python 2.7 on-board the PlayBook, for now, but it's inaccessible (locked-down tight) and -- I believe -- will be removed at some point in the future so it's not an option.

Comment: You could also give a try to Python interactive console for BlackBerry 10, it's a derivative work of Peter and allows you to test, prototype and build rather quickly.
http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/32880889/

Answer (score 1):

Given the number of platforms you listed,

> iPhone, Symbian, Android, BlackBerry,
>   and Windows Mobile

I'd suggest you look into a web framework you can integrate your logic into.  I know Django is quite popular.  Putting a web-frontend on your app does mean your users do have to be connected to the Internet to use your application and you have to have it hosted publicly on the Internet- but I think the Pros far outweigh the Cons.

If you develop your application to run on the phone, you have to address every platform you want it to run on; conversely, if you host your app on the web, any standards compliant browser should be able to present your application to the user.  This also means the application isn't tied to the device. Should the user change phones, or loose their phone- the application (and their data) is not lost or compromised.

This also means the users can access the application from their desktop, tablet, nettop, PS3, wifi-connected toaster etc.

I know this isn't really what you are looking for; its a suggestion to the fundamental design of your application; but with the little info you've posted about the application- there was nothing suggesting it 'can not' be hosted on a the web using standards compliant technologies.

FWIW- making a mobile application more 'future proof' will only pay out in the end. mobile platforms change faster then just about any other consumer technology.

My $0.02

Comment: Thanks for the insight. However, I'm still stuck on wondering if there is a way to turn a compiled file written in Python to a BlackBerry device.